# how can I show that the integral is convergent $\int_1^\infty\ e^{-x} dx$ and that it is equal to $1/e$

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

After having the $0<e^{−x}$ for all x≥1,and we see $$\int_1^\infty\ e^{−x} dx$$

so $I_0$ converge, $$dx=1/e$$

Moreover, for any natural number n non-zero, $$I_n= \int_1^n x^{n}e^{−x} dx$$

Using part integration, for any real $$M>1$$

Is there something I missed? The solution says that we can verify $$\int_1^M x^{n+1}e^{−x}dx = - M^{n+1}/e^{M}+1/e+ \int_1^M (n+1)x^{n}e^{−x} dx$$

Having said that, how do you reach this conclusion?

Comment: If you want to put periods in displays, they have to come before the `$$`

Comment: Did you mean $1/e$ where you typed $1/2$ in the title?

Comment: The proof involving integration by parts doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question in the title (which can be answered by observing that $\int e^{-x}dx = - e^{-x}$).

Comment: This is unclear. Are you asking about the convergence of just $I_0$ or of all $I_n$?

Comment: I removed the shell in the title

Comment: I reformulate, we show that $I0$ is a convergent integral equal to $1/e$ and that every natural number n, the integral $In$ converges

Answer (score 1):

I guess that when you write
$$\int_1^\infty e^{-x}$$
you mean
$$\int_1^\infty e^{-x}dx$$
If this is the case, and given that $\frac{d}{dx}(-e^{-x}) = e^{-x}$, it is trivial to show by the fundamental theorem of calculus that
$$\int_1^\infty e^{-x}dx = \lim_{x\to\infty}(-e^{-x}) - (-e^{-1}) = \frac{1}{e}\neq\frac{1}{2}$$